# Are PDB files useful when code has been obfuscated

Tags: c#, debugging

My understanding is that by placing the associated PDB files next to compiled code, any exception and stack trace will report a filename and line number, which assists with debugging.

Are these files still useful if the code has been obfuscated? e.g. are the filenames and line numbers still correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pdb files generated before obfuscation will not correlate to the obfuscated assembly.  Many obfuscators have an option to generate a PDB file as part of their output.

For example, Dotfuscator has a `Emit Debugging Symbols` option to create a pdb file.  [Obfuscator](http://obfuscar.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Configuration) has a `RegenerateDebugInfo` option to recreate the pdb file.